# How many galaxies have had their distance determined using SNIa?

Tags: galaxy, distances, supernova, standard-candle

Supernovae of type Ia can be used as standard candles to determine extra-galactic distances. But these event only occur (roughly) [once every 200 years in any given galaxy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34778/9527) and rapidly fade away. So to actually see a supernova in another galaxy, you have to be observing a lot of galaxies for a long time. This makes it seem like this isn't a very practical method to determine extra-galactic distances. To how many galaxies has the distance been determined using type Ia supernovae?

Comment: "standard candle" is the keyword :-) Note, in the last 50 years, we could have seen supernova in 25% of the galaxies.

Comment: ...of the galaxies that we have been looking at non stop.

Comment: Enough if we make a single photo about it in the $\approx$ 1 month until the SN is visible.

Comment: This paper mentions using  740 spectroscopically conﬁrmed type Ia supernovae with high quality light curves https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4064

Comment: No, it isn't a good way of determing distances if your aim is to determine the distance to every galaxy. But thast isn't what they are used for.